# Which number remains alive?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are $100$ people standing in a circle numbered from $1$ to $100$. The first person is having a sword and kills the the person standing next to him clockwise i.e $1$ kills $2$ and so on. Which is the last number to remain alive? Also if $1$ kills both the person standing next to him. Which is the last number standing? Can both of them be generalized?

Comment: If $1$ kills $2$, how can $2$ kill $3$?? $2$ is dead!

Comment: i think it is spiritual question :D :D :D

Comment: 3 kills 4, 5 kills 6...goes on till one orperson is left

Comment: but main  question is where is police :D

Comment: I would say $73$. That's my lucky number.

Comment: The barbaric [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Comment: @drhab you are right,i think number 73 drunk something that helps him  to avoid sword :D

Comment: hmmm, why not 63?

Comment: What if the 100 read this math.SE thread first and then played their game? I don't know who'd be left standing, but poor 73 would certainly be the first to die. ;)

Comment: It looks a lot like the Josephus problem, but actually I cannot understand the formulation completely from the text. It could be a different, similar problem. I think that unless we get a clarification there is little point is answering what could possibly be the wrong question.

Comment: For a more in-depth discussion (and near-explicit formula) of this problem than I care to write up in an answer, please see Ch 1 and Ch 3 (not sure on the last one--working from memory) of *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth et. al.  (He's not first author, but he's the only one I remember).  **note:** there are a *lot* of questions here on Math.SE regarding the Josephus problem that could be answered directly with quotes from that book.  In fact, there are a few problems where people said "no nice form exists" for which Knuth *has* derived a "nice closed form."

Comment: And the answer is 42

Answer (score 8):

The first case is similar to Josephus Problem and in general situation, we can use the following MATLAB code to get the remaining number:

### First Case:

```
function RemainNum = JosephusProblem(n,m)
A = 1:n;
A = A';
for k = 1:n-1
  A = circshift(A,length(A)-mod(m+1,length(A)) + 1);
  A = A(1:(end-1));
RemainNum = A;
```

where $n$ is the total number of person in this circle and from the person #1, people count number one by one from 1 to $m$ circularly and the person who tells the number $m$ gets killed and this process doesn't end until there is only one person left, then the function returns this lucky guy by $\text{RemainNum}$. So in this case, $m=2$. People count like $1,2,1,2,...$ and persons who count 2 get killed.

### Second Case:

Let $f(n)$ be the lucky number in this case, then I guess that 
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1,    &\text{if $n=1$}\\
n-1,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
n-2, & \text{if $n$ is odd}  \\
\end{cases}$$
Since every time at most 2 persons are killed and 1 person is killed only when there are only 2 person left, so when $n$ is even, finally there will be only 2 persons left after $\frac{n-2}{2}$ times killing and person $n-1$ gets the sword, so $f(n) = n-1$ in this case. When $n$ is odd, after $\frac{n-3}{2}$ times killing, there will be 3 person left, and person $n-2$ gets the sword and then kills the other two, so $f(n)= n-2$ in this case.

Comment: MathJax wasn't made for code. In Markdown, we use backticks (`\`code\``) for inline code snippets, and four spaces (`<newline>   code`) for "separate" code. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!@Giulio Muscarello

Comment: Oh yeah...Josephus problem. I remember the implementation in C using Linked List.

Comment: Yes, we can use linked list in C and we can also use only array to implement it. In MATLAB, the implementation can be very simple.

Comment: matlab code was cool :)

Answer (score 8):

Write it in binary and shift (with cyclic rotation) one bit left - ;-) 
The closed formula is:
$$
f(n) = 2 \cdot ( n - 2^{\lfloor log_2n \rfloor}) + 1
$$

More details could be found in Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth, chapter 1.3.

Comment: This needs to me marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

**First case** : If 1 kills 2, then 2 can not kill 3 because he is dead. So we are down to every odd number killing the even numbered person. So,
Updating after @coffeemath's  comment

After 1st round: $$1,3,5,7,9\cdots99$$ 
2nd round:$$1,5,9,13\cdots97$$
3rd round:$$1,9,17,25\cdots97$$
4th round:$$9,25,41,57,73,89$$
5th round:$$9,41,73$$
6th round:$$9,73$$

And 73 kills 9 ultimately. :)

To calculate I used an excel sheet and started to mark people alive after 1st round,2nd round and so on.

**Second Case:** 100 is standing next to 1, because they are standing in circle. So, 1 kills 2 and 100 (both even). 3 kills both 1 and 4, cos 1 is alive and next to 3 now and this goes on. So, the sequence

$$\begin{align}\\ 1-100,2\\3-1,4\\5-3,6\\7-5,8\\9-7,10\\...\\...\\99-97
\end{align}$$

There is no one to kill 99. So 99 is alive. :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks, but can we generalize it?

Comment: No, you can't, unfortunately. But I think you can definately write a program for both the cases.

Comment: 99 has just killed 100, so now the sword passes to 1. Thus 1 stays alive after the first "round", and then 3,7 etc get killed next.

Comment: yes, you are right, updating. thanks

Comment: The latter one does appear to generalize, at least for even numbers of people. 1 will always kill 2 and n, and everyone will kill the person behind them, leaving no one to kill n-1. For odd n, it appears to be n-2 who survives.

Comment: I think the first case would be a little easier to follow if you included the "wrap-around kills" in the earlier round, thus starting every round with the first killing the second.

Comment: My take on this whole generalization thing is that, this is not an algebric sequence or a problem, but more of a logical thing. So, we might fail giving it an algebric look. Again this is my personal view :)

Comment: To make things complete also mention the number of the person that carries the sword after what you call a round. After e.g. the $5$th round it is number $9$ (first number), but after what you call the $6$th round it is number $73$ (last number). So there is some inconsistency there.

Comment: The generalisation is along the lines of 2*(n - (highest power of two lower than n) ) +1(depending in if you start the count at zero or 1)

Answer (score 6):

This is for the first case, where killing proceeds only clockwise. Let $f(n)$ be the position of the last person alive. Then we can show two recursive statements to determine $f(n)$ (given the initial $f(1)=1$):
$$f(2n)=2f(n)-1, \\ f(2n+1)=2f(n)+1.$$
For the $f(2n)$ case, the remaining numbers after one round are $2\cdot 1-1,\cdots 2n-1.$ (and the $1$ is alive on the next round) This is a list of $n$ numbers $2k-1,$ with $1 \le k \le n$ So if we know the value of $f(n)$ we can just adjust it to where it is on this list, and get $2f(n)-1$ for $f(2n).$

For the $f(2n+1)$ case, one round again kills the even indexed values, but the last position $2n+1$ now holds the sword and will then kill $1$, so that we are left with the numbers of the list $2\cdot 1+1, \cdots, 2n+1$ (with the $3$ alive) which is again a list of $n$ numbers, so that similarly to the above if we know $f(n)$ we can adjust it to where it is on this list to get $2f(n)+1$ for the value of $f(2n+1).$

Applying these recursions to $f(100)$ we have
$$f(100)=2f(50)-1,\\ f(50)=2f(25)-1,\\ f(25)=2f(12)+1,\\ f(12)=2f(6)-1,\\ 
f(6)=2f(3)-1,\\ f(3)=2f(1)+1.$$
Then plugging in $f(1)=1$ and working upward gives $f(100)=73$ (as in MonK's answer).

These recursions would give $f(n)$ for any $n$ but aren't in a closed form, which would be nicer.

*Added:* By looking at $n$ in base 2 and using the above recursions, one can get the following "almost" closed form. If $2^k \le n < 2^{k+1}$ then 
$$f(n)=2(n-2^k)+1.$$
In particular $f(n)$ must be odd in all cases, something unexpected (to me). This form is another version of the one cited by fex in his answer above, from Knuth.

Comment: Actually that $f(n)$ is odd is clear since in round one all the evens get killed, for any $n.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, in C. The answer is 73.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
void main(){
    int i=0, j; //i has the sword, j gets killed.
    int a[N]={0}; //0=not killed
    while(1){
        if(i != N-1) j = i + 1;
        else j = 0;
        while(a[j])
            if((j + 1) == N) j = 0; //loop back to 0
            else j++; //skip over the killed people
        if(i==j){ //if i is the only one left, stop
            printf("\n\n\n%d is left!", i+1);
            return;
        }
        a[j] = 1; //kill j
        printf(" %d kills %d.", i+1, j+1);
        if(j != N-1) i = j + 1;
        else i=0;
        while(a[i])
            if((i + 1) == N) i = 0;
            else i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok  because $1$ kill $2$ ,then $3$ kill $4$,that means that we have odd numbers after one round

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
31
33
35
37
39
41
43
45
47
49
51
53
55
57
59
61
63
65
67
69
71
73
75
77
79
81
83
85
87
89
91
93
95
97
99
```

now we are continuing again or ?after another round we have these numbers

```
1

5

9

13

17

21

25

29

33

37

41

45

49

53

57

61

65

69

73

77

81

85

89

93

97
```

final result is 73

Comment: Yes! It continues till 1 person is left.

Comment: next stage 1 kills 3,5 kills 7,7 kills 9 and so on right

Comment: 99 kills 100 now the sword is with 1, and now 3, 7, 11...are dead and it continues.

Comment: Can u generalize it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem please look on this problem

Comment: Too good, this is what I wanted. Thank you so much...:)

Comment: you are welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

Second case if we have m guys at the table:

survivor = m-($m\pmod2$)-1

$1->m,2$

(for 0$<$n$<$(m-2)/2)

$2*n+1$$->$$2*n-1$,$2*n+2$

then the last guy kill someone is $(m-1)->(m-3)$ or $(m-2)->(m-1),(m-4)$ and from there because of its value depends on modulo 2, $survivor = m-($$m\pmod2$$)-1$.

First case if we have m guys at the table:

$n=floor(\log_{2}m)$

$survivor = 2*(m-2^n)+1$

if length is even

$a->a+k,a+2*k->a+3*k,..,a+(n-1)*k->a+n*k$

$a,a+2*k,a+4*k,..,a+(n-1)*k$

if length is odd

$a->a+k,a+2*k->a+3*k,..,a+(n-2)*k->a+(n-1)*k,a+n*k->a$

$a+2*k,a+4*k,a+6*k,..,a+n*k$

If we always make length half and survivor changes only $\pmod2$ is equal to 1 then I thought if we thought that number as a binary then the digits which are zero is make survivor less then the m is $m-binaryInverse(m)$ is equal to survivor then it is same with $survivor = 2*(m-2^n)+1$. Sorry for my english but i try to make it better.

Comment: [Please use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.

Comment: Please can you explain how you arrived?

Answer (score -1):

Last Survival is 61 as shown in below matrix

1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th Final Round

1   1   1   5   13  29  61
2   3   5   13  29  61
3   5   9   21  45  93
4   7   13  29  61
5   9   17  37  77
6   11  21  45  93
7   13  25  53
8   15  29  61
9   17  33  69
10  19  37  77
11  21  41  85
12  23  45  93
13  25  49
14  27  53
15  29  57
16  31  61
17  33  65
18  35  69
19  37  73
20  39  77
21  41  81
22  43  85
23  45  89
24  47  93
25  49  97
26  51
27  53
28  55
29  57
30  59
31  61
32  63
33  65
34  67
35  69
36  71
37  73
38  75
39  77
40  79
41  81
42  83
43  85
44  87
45  89
46  91
47  93
48  95
49  97
50  99
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100

$${}$$

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution in Python : Not an elegant mathematical one ; but since I did not know the mathematically

```
from itertools import cycle
NUMBER = 100
people = list(range(1, NUMBER + 1))
dead = []
print  "Runing"

print people
people_list = cycle(people)

while len(people) != 1:
    tolive = next(people_list)
    if tolive not in dead:
        todel = next(people_list)

    if todel not in dead:
        dead.append(todel)
    else:
        people = set(people) - set(dead)
        print sorted(people)
        people_list = cycle(sorted(people))

print people
print "over"
```

For 100 it is 73

Answer (score -1):

this can be solved using mathematics of induction.

> winner=(total_people - (2^i - 1 - total_people))

here `i` can be calculated using this equation:

> 2^i <= total_people < 2^(i+1)

Here's the c++ implementation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int i,total_people;

    while(true){
        cin>>total_people;
        i=0;
        while(pow(2,i)<=total_people){
            i++;
        }
        i--;
        int winner=(total_people-(pow(2,i+1)-1-total_people));
        cout<<winner;

    }

}
```